# How to delete record from the database?

Tags: laravel

Can't delete record from the database. It says resource is not found.

Service:

```
public function delete(Location $location): Location
{
    if ($this->deleteById($location->id)) {
        return $location;
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
 public function destroy(Location $location) {
    $this->locationService->delete($location);
    return redirect()->route('admin.location.index');
 }
```

The way I stored it is this way. Some of these data are from google map stored via JS script

Service:

```
 public function store(array $data = []): Location
 {
    DB::beginTransaction();

    try {
        $location = $this->createLocation([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'address_latitude' => $data['address_latitude'],
            'address_longitude' => $data['address_longitude'],
        ]);

    } catch (Exception $e) {
        DB::rollBack();

        throw new GeneralException(__('There was a problem creating this resource. Please try again.'));
    }

    DB::commit();

    return $location;
 }
```

Controller:

```
  public function store(Request $request) {
    $location = $this->locationService->store($request->all());
    return redirect()->route('admin.location.index', $location)->withFlashSuccess(__('The location was successfully added.'));
  }
```

Comment: Did you try `$location->delete()` ?

Comment: @Bazaim yes. I tried it on my service class. the response is successfully deleted yet nothing happens on my view and database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 public function destroy(Location $location) {
    $location->delete();
    return redirect()->route('admin.location.index');
 }
```

Comment: just redirects. nothing happened. is there a workaround on this one? one data is actually from an input field and the other two is stored via dragging a map marker. i thought maybe it's the way i stored the data will be also the way i have to delete it if i'm right.

Comment: No i think this is the best way to delete it.. can I see your routes?

Comment: Route::delete('/', [LocationController::class, 'destroy'])->name('destroy');

just a note:

when I try to do:

  public function destroy(Location $location)
    {  
        return $location->find(9)->delete();
    }

in my Service it works fine. My problem now is to dynamically get the model id else it returns null.

Comment: Try Route::delete('{location}', 'LocationController'); in your route
and  public function destroy(Location $location) {
    $location->delete();
    return redirect()->route('admin.location.index');
 }
In your controller.